# Has anyone recently applied for Schengen visa for Netherlands? In how many days did you receive your visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, netherlands, vfs-global

I had applied for Schengen visa for Netherlands from San Francisco on 22nd July 2022. It's been 3 weeks now, in my past experience three times I always received it within 2 weeks. Now I am worried if this would impact my travel as I am scheduled to travel on Sept 1 (Hope I receive it before that). Has anyone experienced similar experience recently in 2022? In how many days/weeks did you receive your visa? VFS off course is unable to provide response as my passport is with embassy for further processing and not sure if sending email to NL embassy would be helpful.

Comment: Visa applications are taking longer than normal pretty much everywhere. The VFS website https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/nld/news/longer-waiting-time-for-visa-applications states “it may take longer than 15 days to process your application.
This is because a growing number of applicants wants to travel to the Netherlands after COVID travel restrictions have been eased worldwide.
Plan your trip well in advance.”

Comment: Yeah I read the news but not sure how much more time it takes as incase of longer I would need to reschedule my flight . My appointment was on 22nd July and my flight is on 1st september .

Comment: Did your status show it got sent to the embassy? i applied 2 weeks ago and the tracking still shows it at the Visa processing service

Comment: This is why the experience of one person is almost never useful for an other person, the details are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's time for San Francisco NL embassy if anyone faces similar issue

22nd July 2022 : Applied at VFS NL VAS center at 2 pm

25th July 2022: Application reaches NL embassy at SF

9th August 2022: Status shows "Application Processed by Embassy and passport returned to VFS office "

10th August 2022 : FedEx shipment initiated for courier from VFS to my home

11th August 2022: Receive my passport with Schengen visa .